# Jquery-mobile : Title from previous page still present

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, web2py

I'm using **Web2py** and using the "**PLUGIN_JQMOBILE/LAYOUT.HTML**" as the base layout file.

The problem is that when I click on a link, jquery-mobile takes me to the next page -- all fine here.

`When I view the source for the page, I see that it still has <title> from the older page.`

I caught the problem since I'm using lockerz(addToAny.com) and when users try to share the page on Facebook, the title was coming completely incorrect.

I used the [FB developers debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) page & saw the title shown.

I can add the og:title, etc, but this problem is biting me for Google+ as well.

Am I doing something incorrect or is that a side-effect of jquery-mobile.. ?

Comment: Manualy change your jquery template, inside title tag should be this: {{=response.title or request.application}} change it to {{=response.title}}

Comment: I've already done that inside PLUGIN_JQMOBILE/LAYOUT.HTML -->  <title>{{=response.title}}</title>

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the Ajax loading by default in jQuery Mobile. You can avoid this problem by using data-ajax="false" in your links or by using a jQuery script to change the page title after loading.